# Get time formatter string for AM / PM without using time

Tags: swift, datetime-format

Is there a way to get AM / PM localized string from time formatter without using any given time?

Something like:

```
let locale = Locale(identifier: "en-us")
        
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = locale
formatter.dateFormat = "a"
```

and somehow print "am" and "pm" variant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get it from `Calendar`, using the [`amSymbol`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293634-amsymbol) and [`pmSymbol`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2292945-pmsymbol) properties.

```
var calendar = Calendar.current
// set the locale if you want am/pm for a non-current locale
// calendar.locale = someLocale
let am = calendar.amSymbol
let pm = calendar.pmSymbol
```